# copy assignment operator with volatile qualifier

Tags: c++, templates, volatile, crtp, trivially-copyable

Below, I used template<int = 0> learnt from @Daniel McLaury in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74050878/why-non-volatile-t-with-conversion-from-volatile-t-to-t-should-be-non-trivial).

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct A_base {
    int val;

    // template<int = 0> // needs it to make MSVC work
    volatile T& operator=(const volatile T& a) volatile {
        val = a.val;
        return static_cast<volatile T&>(*this);
    }

    T& operator=(const volatile T& a) {
        val = a.val;
        return static_cast<T&>(*this);
    }
};

struct A : A_base<A> {
    using A_base::operator=;

    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = default;

    template<int = 0>
    A(const volatile A& a) {
        *this = a;
    }
};

void test(volatile A* p) {
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<A>);

    A a = *p;
    *p = a;
}
```

Both GCC and Clang can compile the code, but MSVC failed:

> error C2678: binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand
> operand of type 'volatile A' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
> message : could be 'A &A::operator =(const A &)' message : or
> 'A_base &A_base::operator =(const A_base &)' message : or
> 'A_base &A_base::operator =(A_base &&)' message : while
> trying to match the argument list '(volatile A, A)'

I need template<int = 0> on the CRTP **volatile T& operator=(const volatile T& a) volatile;** to make MSVC work.

I guess it's because templated code has lower priority in the overload resolution rule, is that true?

Could someone review my code, and explain which part is illegal/undefined by C++ standard?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This gives me compiler warnings under gcc.  I think it's probably worth being a little more explicit about what some of these assignments are intended to do.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury If the warning is "warning: implicit dereference will not access object of type..." Yes, that's expected.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Report it as a MSVC bug.